# Edit and update function is not working in angular code

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am facing problem on editing the form. I'm not able to get the form values on clicking edit button. Only the values are visible in console. And update button is also not working.

**prepaid.component.html**

```
<div><button style="margin:10px 0 0 50px;"mat-raised-button color="warn" routerLink="/addPlan"><mat-icon >add_circle_outline</mat-icon>Add Plan</button>
</div>

<div class="container" id="main-container">
  <div style="margin-top:10px">
      <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Ex." #input>
        </mat-form-field>
        
        <div ngFor="let row of plan" class="mat-elevation-z8">
          <table [dataSource]="dataSource" mat-table matSort>
            
            
            <!-- ID Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planType">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Type </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.planType}} </td>
            </ng-container>
        
            <!-- Progress Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planName">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> PlanName </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.planName}} </td>
            </ng-container>
        
            <!-- Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planPrice">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Price </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> Rs.{{row?.planPrice}} </td>
            </ng-container>
        
            <!-- Fruit Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planDescription">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.planDescription}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Fruit Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planOffers">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Offers </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.planOffers}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Fruit Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="planValidity">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Validity </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.planValidity}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Fruit Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
                
              <a mat-icon-button color="primary"  routerLink="/editPlan/{{row.id}}" (click)="editPlan(row,row.id)">
                  <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
              </a> 
              <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="deletePlan(row.id)">
                  <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
              </button>     
              </td>
            </ng-container>


        
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        
            <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
            <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
              <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data matching the filter "{{input.value}}"</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        
          <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 25, 100]" aria-label="Select page of users"></mat-paginator>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**prepaid.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AddPlanComponent } from '../add-plan/add-plan.component';
import { AdminApiService } from '../services/admin-api.service';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { Plan } from 'src/app/plan';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prepaid',
  templateUrl: './prepaid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prepaid.component.css']
})
export class PrepaidComponent implements OnInit {
  plan!: Plan[];
  plandata!: Plan;
  editPlanData!:FormGroup;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['planType', 'planName', 'planPrice','planDescription','planOffers','planValidity','action'];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;


  
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,public dialog: MatDialog,private api:AdminApiService,private route:ActivatedRoute) {}


  ngOnInit(): void{
    this.getPrePlan();

    this.editPlanData=this.formBuilder.group({
      id:[''],
      planName:[''],
      planType:[''],
      planPrice:[''],
      planOffers:[''],
      planValidity:[''],
      planDescription:['']
      
    });
  }
  

  public getPrePlan():void{
    this.api.getPlans()
    .subscribe({
      next:(response:Plan[])=>{
        this.plan=response;
        this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
        
      },
      error:()=>{
        alert("Error while fetching records")
      }
    });
  }

  deletePlan(id:number){
    this.api.deletePlan(id)
    .subscribe({
      next:(res)=>{
        alert("Plan deleted successfully");
        this.getPrePlan();
      },
      error:()=>{
        alert("error on deleting");
      }
    });

  }
  editPlan(response:Plan,id:number){
    /*this.editPlanData.controls['id'].setValue(response.id);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planName'].setValue(response.planName);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planPrice'].setValue(response.planPrice);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planType'].setValue(response.planType);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planOffers'].setValue(response.planOffers);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planDescription'].setValue(response.planDescription);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planValidity'].setValue(response.planValidity);*/
    console.log(response);

  }

  }
```

**edit-plan.component.html**

```
<div id="Editplan" class="example-container">
    <form ngFor="let editPlan of plan" [formGroup]="editPlanData">
      <mat-form-field hidden appearance="outline">
        <mat-label hidden>id</mat-label>
        <input hidden  matInput placeholder="Enter plan name" id="id" formControlName="id">
      </mat-form-field>
  
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter plan name</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter plan name" id="planName" formControlName="planName" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter the plan price</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter the plan price" type="number" id="planPrice" formControlName="planPrice" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter plan type</mat-label>
          <mat-select id="planType" formControlName="planType" required>
              <mat-option value="Prepaid">Prepaid</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter the offer for the plan</mat-label>
          <mat-select id="planOffers" formControlName="planOffers" required>
              <mat-option value="Netflix">Netflix</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Amazon">Amazon</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="Hotstar">Hotstar</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="No Offer">None</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter plan validity</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Enter plan validity" id="planValidity" formControlName="planValidity" required>
        </mat-form-field>
      
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Enter plan description</mat-label>
          <textarea matInput placeholder="Enter plan description" id="planDescription" formControlName="planDescription" required></textarea>
        </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  
    <div mat-dialog-action [align]="'end'">
        <button class="save-btn" id="plan-details" mat-raised-button color="warn">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**edit-plan.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Plan } from '../plan';
import { AdminApiService } from '../services/admin-api.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-plan',
  templateUrl: './edit-plan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-plan.component.css']
})
export class EditPlanComponent implements OnInit {
  public plan!: Plan[];
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  public editPlan!: Plan;
  editPlanData!:FormGroup;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,private api: AdminApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editPlanData=this.formBuilder.group({
      id:[''],
      planName:[''],
      planType:[''],
      planPrice:[''],
      planOffers:[''],
      planValidity:[''],
      planDescription:['']
      
    });



    /*this.editPlanData.controls['id'].setValue(this.editPlan.id);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planName'].setValue(this.editPlan.planName);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planPrice'].setValue(this.editPlan.planPrice);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planType'].setValue(this.editPlan.planType);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planOffers'].setValue(this.editPlan.planOffers);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planDescription'].setValue(this.editPlan.planDescription);
    this.editPlanData.controls['planValidity'].setValue(this.editPlan.planValidity);*/
  }
  public getPrePlan():void{
    this.api.getPlans()
    .subscribe({
      next:(response:Plan[])=>{
        this.plan=response;
        this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(response);
        this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
        
      },
      error:()=>{
        alert("Error while fetching records")
      }
    });
  }

  public OnUpdatePlan(editForm:NgForm): void{
    this.api.updatePlan(this.editPlan.id,editForm.value)
    .subscribe({
      next:(response:Plan)=>{
        console.log(response);
        this.getPrePlan();
      },
      error:()=>{
        alert("Error while adding records")
      }
    });


  }

}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Plan } from 'src/app/plan'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminApiService { 
  private apiServerUrl=environment.apiBaseUrl;
  
  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
  
  public getPlans(): Observable<Plan[]> {
    return this.http.get<Plan[]>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/prepaid-plan/all`);
  }

  public addPlan(plan: Plan): Observable<Plan> {
    return this.http.post<Plan>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/prepaid-plan/add`, plan);
  }

  updatePlan(planId:number,plan:Plan): Observable<Plan>{
    return this.http.put<Plan>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/prepaid-plan/update/`+planId,plan);
  }

  public deletePlan(planId: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete<void>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/prepaid-plan/delete/${planId}`);
  }
  


  
}
```

**plan.ts**

```
export interface Plan {
    id: number;
    planName: string;
    planType: string;
    planPrice: string;
    planOffers: string;
    planDescription: string;
    planValidity: string;
  }
```

Output one

[image]

output on clicking edit button

[image]

How to get the values in the edit form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,
you didn't call setValue

> this.editPlanData.setValue(response);

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 this.editPlanData=this.formBuilder.group({
  id:[''],
  planName:[''],
  planType:[''],
  planPrice:[''],
  planOffers:[''],
  planValidity:[''],
  planDescription:['']
  });
  this.getPrePlan();
 } 
public getPrePlan():void{
this.api.getPlans()
.subscribe({
  next:(response:Plan)=>{
    this.plan=response;
    this.editPlanData.setValue(response);
    this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(response);
    this.dataSource.paginator=this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort=this.sort;
    
  },
  error:()=>{
    alert("Error while fetching records")
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you has two approach:

1. Pass as parameter the Id to the page (it's looks like you have in
   the code). For this you need read the parameter, subscribe to the
   params, call to the service and fill the form, like indicate in the
   [docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#accessing-query-parameters-and-fragments)
2. Pass data between the routers like [this link](https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb) show